# Excel sum by quarter, based on the first month date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns. The Sum by Quarter column is the topic of the question - I don't know how to implement it.

```
Date          Price      Sum by Quarter
1-Aug-14      150        350
1-Sep-14      200        =""
1-Oct-14      100        =""
1-Nov-14      500        800
1-Dec-14      200        =""
1-Jan         300        =""
1-Feb         50         650
1-Mar         300        =""
```

...and so on

The first date in the column is the month of =TODAY() function, therefore it will change as the time passes by. So in September I would expect to see this:

```
Date          Price      Sum by Quarter
1-Sep-14      200        200
1-Oct-14      100        =""
1-Nov-14      500        800
1-Dec-14      200        =""
1-Jan         300        =""
1-Feb         50         650
1-Mar         300        =""
```

...and so on

And in October this:

```
Date          Price      Sum by Quarter
1-Oct-14      100        =""
1-Nov-14      500        800
1-Dec-14      200        =""
1-Jan         300        =""
1-Feb         50         650
1-Mar         300        =""
```

...and so on

What function would you use in sum by quarter colum so that it keeps correctly calculating the sum and displaying it in this format?

Comment: What don't you use Pivot Tables ?

Comment: I can't format them as freely as cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to sum by quarter in one single formula, but not how to put in those empty strings two months out of three. For that I need a second formula in a different column.

The formula in cell C2 is:

```
=SUM(IF(CEILING.PRECISE(MONTH($A$2:$A$34)/3)=CEILING.PRECISE(MONTH(A2)/3),1,0)
    *IF(YEAR($A$2:$A$34)=YEAR(A2),1,0)*$B$2:$B$34)
```

entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and copied down.

In "Sum by quarter" I cheated and applied conditional formatting to semi-hide the months that should have been empty strings. In the next column there's a second formula which does convert those to actual empty strings.

FYI `CEILING.PRECISE(MONTH($A$2:$A$34)/3` converts month number (1-12) to quarter number (1-4).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will keep trying to figure out the hiding part, hopefully without any extra columns

Comment: Actually using conditional formatting was enough - really appreciate your assistance here